# databricks partition date by week

Tags: pyspark, partitioning, azure-databricks

I'm new to databricks and trying to create partition.I've 3 columns available for partition i.e name,value and date.The required condition is that partition of date should be on weekly basis.
I've done something like this :

```
df\
.write\
.format("delta")\
.partitionBy(["name","value" and "date"]).
.save(writePath)
```

I don't know how to partition date by week ? I came across `repartitionByRange` but not sure how to apply for my condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new columns `week` and `year` from the `date` column and use them in partitionby:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("week", F.weekofyear("date")) \
.withColumn("year", F.year("date")) \
.write \
.format("delta") \
.partitionBy("year", "week") \
.save(writePath)
```

Note that the week number alone is not sufficient as it depends also on the year.

Comment: I've 2 other fields other than date.Can i add them as .partitionBy("year", "week","name","value") ?

Comment: having too many columns as partition will generate too many small files. On Databricks you may improve performance by indexing them (so-called data skipping), apply ZOrder, etc.

Comment: @Van_jss yes, you can add them, but it depends on your use case and as emphasized by Alex, avoid having so many partitions, you'll have no benefits, worse you can degrade performance.